# Temporal table retrieves partitioned sets of rows with different order by a strange pattern

Tags: sql

I am solving a task based on Adventure Works 2012.

**For each fiscal year (2007 and 2008), find the first dates when the cumulative running revenue total hit $10 million.**

The output should include the following columns:

- Fiscal year (2007 or 2008).
- Order date in which $10 million was reached or exceeded.
- Order count within the fiscal year in which $10 million was reached or exceeded (for example, if the $10 million goal was reached on the 50th order, then the appropriate value to report is 50).
- Order ID where the $10 million goal was reached.
- Running total revenue in which $10 million was reached or exceeded.

```
DROP TABLE #data
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, OrderDate)) FiscalYear, CAST(OrderDate AS DATE) OrderDate, SalesOrderID OrderID,
COUNT(*)        OVER(Partition BY YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, OrderDate)) ORDER BY SalesOrderID) OrderCount,
SUM(SubTotal)   OVER(Partition BY YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, OrderDate)) ORDER BY SalesOrderID) RunTotal
INTO #data
FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, OrderDate)) IN (2007, 2008)

SELECT TOP 1 FiscalYear, OrderDate, OrderCount, OrderID, RunTotal
FROM #data
WHERE RunTotal>=10000000 AND FiscalYear=2007
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 FiscalYear, OrderDate, OrderCount, OrderID, RunTotal
FROM #data
WHERE RunTotal>=10000000 AND FiscalYear=2008
```

The temporal table #data retrieves correct set partitioned by a FiscalYear and ordered within the partition by an OrderID for 3 consecutive executions and renders correct result in the following UNION query
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjJtd.png)

But then, in the next 2 executions the order gets shuffled: a few thousands of 2008 FiscalYear rows push up the recordset disregarding the COUNT order, and the result for the 2008 (TOP 1) becomes incorrect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjJtd.png)

Then it goes back to normal for 3 executions and so on. Whenever I erase

```
SUM(SubTotal)   OVER(Partition BY YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, OrderDate)) ORDER BY SalesOrderID) RunTotal
```

from the temporal table, the order works fine. I am confused with this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The `TOP` clause makes no sense without `ORDER BY`. In your query you are saying "from all result rows with FiscalYear xxxx and RunTotal >= 10000000 pick a row arbitrarily". The reason for this is that table data is considered an unordered set of data. Without `ORDER BY` there is no guaranteed order.

Hence:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT TOP 1 FiscalYear, OrderDate, OrderCount, OrderID, RunTotal
  FROM #data
  WHERE RunTotal >= 10000000 AND FiscalYear = 2007
  ORDER BY RunTotal
) year2007
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT TOP 1 FiscalYear, OrderDate, OrderCount, OrderID, RunTotal
  FROM #data
  WHERE RunTotal >= 10000000 AND FiscalYear = 2008
  ORDER BY RunTotal
) year2008;
```

I've changed `UNION` to `UNION ALL`, because there are no duplicates to remove.

A query result is again a table. So, the same rule applies: If you want some particular order, you need `ORDER BY`. If you want year 2007 before 2008, add `ORDER BY FiscalYear` to the end of the query.

Comment: Tried this. Does not work: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'." I don't think you can use ORDER BY before UNION, only after. Besides, there is ORDER BY SalesOrderID in the underlying temporal table, so why additional ordering needed?

Comment: Table data is an unordered set of data, no matter what partitions or indexes exist. You need `ORDER BY` to get a guaranteed result order. As to the syntax error: maybe SQL Server doesn't allow this simple query and needs additional select clauses. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thorsten, thank you for the solution, as well as for the explanations. So, I guess, although there is a pattern in the order of the recordset, retrieved by the temporal table, in fact it is still random. Now it works fine!